# Powershell command to sort processes based on thread count

Tags: powershell, process

I'm trying to write a script that will list all active processes with the amount of threads they are using and then sort them from most threads to least.

What I have currently is hacked together and doesn't sort on active threads:

```
get-process | %{$_.Name;$_.Threads | %{$_.ID }| measure-object -line}
```

Anyone know of a better way to go about this?

Comment: **Question:** Are you living up to that avatar/handle name? Lol... hilarious, thanks for the laugh!! FYI... Here's another good one for a laugh that I'd rather not ask the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440558/sucky-sucky-for-one-dollar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are not telling it to sort on anything. This is what the Sort-Object cmdlet is for. Yet, I'd take a different approach here:

For example:

```
Get-Process | 
Select-Object Name, ID, @{Name='ThreadCount';Expression ={$_.Threads.Count}} | 
Sort-Object -Property ThreadCount -Descending

Name                       Id ThreadCount
----                       -- -----------
System                      4         251
sqlservr                 7816         103
iexplore                  412          87
Memory Compression       3176          74
SkypeHost               11952          58
explorer                 6568          51
```